Constructing metric terms for high order elements
Given 27 $(x,y,z)$ coordinates in 3D space which describe a generally curved quadratic hexahedron, which correspond to the HEXA_27 reference element figure with planar faces in $(\xi, \eta, \zeta)$ coordinates. Nodes constructed on the interior by tensor-products of Gauss-Legendre nodes need associated metric terms at those nodes, $\partial(x,y,z)/\partial(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$.
How does one compute those metric terms given those 3D points as input?


I don't think I understand your question. If you have the 27 points' coordinates in real space, that defines the mapping from $(\xi,\eta,\zeta)$ to $(x,y,z)$. Can you explain in more detail what it is you then need? What are, in formulas, the metric terms you mention?

The details of connecting the dots to actually compute the mapping, in particular mapping of gauss-legendre points from the reference element to the physical one -- is the idea you construct 27 multivariate lagrange interpolants? then what?

Let's assume you have a way of computing the 27 tri-quadratic shape functions associated with the 27 points (either by tabulating them as polynomials, or by computing them as interpolating Lagrange polynomials satisfying $\varphi_i(\vec \xi_j) = \delta_{ij}$), then the mapping from the reference cell is provided by
$$
  \vec x(\vec\xi) = \sum_{i=1}^{27} \vec v_i \varphi_i(\vec\xi)
$$
where $\vec v_i$ are the 27 node positions in real space.
You use this mapping applied to the reference location of quadrature points to determine their real-space location. The Jacobian matrix of this mapping is given by
$$
  J(\vec\xi) = \sum_{i=1}^{27} \vec v_i \otimes \nabla\varphi_i(\vec\xi)
$$
(or its transpose, depending on how exactly you define the Jacobian).
